# Create an AxiosError object for test purpose

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios

I am looking for a way to easily create `AxiosError` (from the axios lib itself or an external  helper)

### The context.

I have this function that I want to test.

```
import { AxiosError } from 'axios';

export function isEmailConflict({ error }: { error: AxiosError<{ type?: string; message?: string }> }) {
// ...
}
```

So far I performed it in this way

```
import { AxiosError } from 'axios';
// ...
  describe('isEmailConflict', () => {
    function newConflicError(): AxiosError {
      return {
        isAxiosError: true,
        name: '',
        message: '',
        toJSON: () => ({}),
        config: {},
        response: {
          data: { type: 'aa', message: 'bb' },
          status: 409,
          statusText: 'Conflict',
          headers: {},
          config: {},
        },
      };
    }

    it('should return true if the passed error is of type email already used', () => {
      const error = newConflicError();
      //...
    });
```

but I find it ugly, is there an easy way to create an `AxiosError` ?

I already tried [ts-auto-mock](https://github.com/Typescript-TDD/ts-auto-mock) but I find it too intrusive in my tests config.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From `axios` v1.0.0, it added the `AxiosError` to `AxiosStatic`, see [PR](https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/4654).

```js
// Expose AxiosError class
axios.AxiosError = require('../lib/core/AxiosError');
```

This means you can import the `AxiosError` class from `axios` module and create an `axios` error instance directly. It may be useful for testing.

E.g. (using *axios 1.3.4*)

```
import { AxiosError, AxiosHeaders } from "axios";

var request = { path: "/foo" };
const headers = new AxiosHeaders();
const config = {
  url: "http://localhost:3000",
  headers
};
var error = new AxiosError("Boom!", "ESOMETHING", config, request, {
  status: 200,
  data: { foo: "bar" },
  statusText: "ok",
  config,
  headers
});

console.log("axios error: ", error);

export function isEmailConflict(error: AxiosError) {
  // ...
}
isEmailConflict(error);
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-germain-uj9sij?file=/src/index.ts:0-460)

Answer (score 7):

Meanwhile, I had to switch to **TypeScript**, where this is the solution that worked for me (without `axios-error`):

```
import axios, { AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse } from "axios";
import { AxiosError } from "axios";

[...]

  const responseData = "some string";
  const response: AxiosResponse = {
    data: responseData,
    status: 500,
  } as AxiosResponse;
  const axiosError = {
    config: {},
    request: {},
    response: response} as AxiosError<any>;
```

Answer (score 2):

I used this package recently, its examples work like a charm

[image]
https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-error

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue where I created a utility method to check if it was an Axios error or an error from the error instance.

```
import { AxiosError, isAxiosError } from 'axios';

// Get error message based on the error type which could be Error or AxiosError
export const getErrorMessage = (
  error: Error | AxiosError | unknown,
): string => {
  if (isAxiosError(error)) {
    return error.response?.data.message || error.message;
  }

  if (error instanceof Error) {
    return error.message;
  }

  if (typeof error === 'string') {
    return error;
  }

  if ((error as Error)?.message) {
    return (error as Error).message;
  }

  // If we don't know what the error is, return a generic message
  // This should never happen
  return 'Something went wrong and we are not sure what it is.';
};
```

I wrote the following test cases to test this function:

```
import { getErrorMessage } from './error-handler';

describe('ErrorHandler utility test suite', () => {
  test('should return default message', () => {
    expect(getErrorMessage(null)).toBe(
      'Something went wrong and we are not sure what it is.',
    );
  });

  test('should return error message', () => {
    expect(getErrorMessage('test')).toBe('test');
  });

  test('should return error message from Error instance', () => {
    expect(getErrorMessage(new Error('test'))).toBe('test');
  });

  test('should return error message from AxiosError instance', () => {
    expect(
      getErrorMessage({
        isAxiosError: true,
        response: {
          data: {
            message: 'test',
          },
        },
      }),
    ).toBe('test');
  });
});
```